# Is it possible to recover a lost stickies note?

Tags: data-recovery, stickies

I use Stickies very much, and some of them are very lengthy and important to me.

Suddenly I lost a sticky which contained crucial information I need to recover. I don't know why it doesn't appear anymore since I don't remember closing it without saving.

Is there any way to recover past stickies? Thank you

Comment: Does @cacosomoza have a TimeMachine backup?

Comment: No, I don't have Time Machine :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've just lost all my sticky notes and don't want to raise a duplicate question.

Comment: nope sorry, I didn't find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to solve this problem, but you can use [yellow](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/yellow/id502844661?mt=12). It is similar to stickies but you can retrieve what you deleted (unless you delete that). Hope this can prevent future mishaps.

Comment: That returns a lot of hits, none of which are called "Yellow" specifically...