# Sticky note saved but cannot be found

Tags: stickies

I saved a Sticky Note before closing it, in the default save location which seems to be MacIntoshHD/User. Now I can't find it, although I haven't deleted it. I don't remember the filename I used, but I know from other sources that it should be an RTF file. Any idea where it is?

I have seen [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7616572) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139467/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-lost-stickies-note).

Comment: does it shows it in `Recent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about the native Stickies app that's part of macOS, all notes are saved in the StickiesDatabase file. This file is located within the user's Library folder, usually located in `Macintosh HD/Users/yourusername/Library`.

If you can't see the `Library` folder, then follow these steps:

1. Click on the Finder icon in your Dock (usually the very first icon)
2. In the Finder window that appears, click on your username in the Sidebar (see note at end if it's not listed)
3. Now go to View > Show View Options (or press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)
4. Now tick the Checkbox next to the Show Library Folder option (it's the bottom checkbox - see screenshot below)

[image]

5. Now your Library folder will be visible

**NOTE:** If your username is not visible in the Sidebar, then go to Finder > Preferences, select the Sidebar tab and then select the checkbox next to your username at the bottom of the Favourites list.

Finally, if by "saved a Sticky Note* you mean you exported it, then by default it'd be saved in your user's home folder unless you navigated to another location when you saved it. In this case, do a search using either Spotlight or Finder's <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> option for the filename you saved it as.

Alternatively, if you don't recall the filename, you can search by the date (or date range) you last saved/opened/modified the file, the contents of the file (assuming you remember some of it), and even by the kind of file (by default Stickies will save as a plain text file).

Comment: Thank you @Monomeeth, but the database file does not contain the saved Sticky. All it contains is a currently open Sticky file. I also do not remember the filename.

Comment: Do you remember *when* you saved it? Or perhaps some of the contents of the note? You can search by these (and other) criteria.

Comment: Thanks again. I remembered I happened to copy/paste the Sticky into TextEdit and saved the .txt file as a backup, so I've found the content of the Sticky that way. Unfortunately, I still can't find the original Sticky file. So I have a workaround. There's nothing in that location that shows an RTF file saved yesterday.

Comment: Maybe do a search by *kind* (i.e. search for files where Kind = Text).

Comment: I have a feeling this answer will be very useful to future folks looking at this post, so I'll accept your answer. Considering I can't find the saved file, I'm starting to question whether I saved it at all. Your answer SHOULD work. Thanks again for your help.